# Any other object-to-object mapping solutions other than AutoMapper in .NET?

Tags: .net, datamapper

I would like to know if the other similar open source solutions in .NET world, especially for 2.0 framework

Answer (score 1):

I've just stumbled upon [ObjectCastor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ObjectToInterfaceCaster.aspx?fid=1539820&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=3017849#xx3017849xx) where the goal is:

> Basically, it generates a new proxy
>   class using the System.CodeDom
>   machinery, which wraps the sourceType
>   and implements the interfaceType
>   interface. With the help of .NET
>   Reflection, it goes over the members
>   of the interfaceType type and
>   generates the corresponding members in
>   the proxy class. After that, it
>   compiles the generated class utilizing
>   the CodeDomProvider class and calling
>   the CompileAssemblyFromDom method. At
>   this point, the generated class is
>   compiled, and the last thing to do is
>   to create a new instance of the proxy
>   class and provide the source object as
>   a constructor. The full source code
>   for the utility class and the demo
>   application are available above in the
>   downloads section.

This technique is now being used in [CS Script](http://www.csscript.net).  From the CSScript help file:

> In version 2.3.3 CS-Script introduces
>   new script hosting model Interface
>   Alignment, which is an attractive
>   alternative to the interface
>   inheritance while loading/accessing
>   scripts through interfaces.
>
> This model allows manipulation with
>   the the script by "aligning" it to the
>   appropriate interface (DuckTyping).
>   Important aspect of this approach is
>   that the script execution is
>   completely typesafe (as with any
>   script accessed through an interface)
>   but even more importantly the script
>   does not have to implement the
>   interface being used by the host
>   application.  In a way Interface
>   Alignment is a forcible typecasting:
>   typecast to interface is possible as
>   long as the object has all methods
>   defined in the interface .   This
>   promising technique allows high level
>   of decoupling between the host and the
>   script business logic without any type
>   safety compromise.

Answer (score 1):

I found out about [otis](http://code.google.com/p/otis-lib/) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286294/object-to-object-mapper/1081480#1081480). It uses String attributes on the classes.

Comment: this one really looks promising, much better than Automapper especially in terms of configuration handling (I very much prefer metadata attributes on classes in Otis than writing like a dozen CreateMap statements in Automapper).

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use CSLA.NET. It provides a Map function.